# SQL Query with comparison operator

Tags: sql, comparison-operators

SQL Noob and still learning. I am trying to figure out how to write a query that will look up all people hired on or after a date and then query another database and pull out all the paychecks those people received so far.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM db2.paychecks 
WHERE paydate >= (SELECT hiredate FROM db1.employees WHERE hiredate >= 2020-01-01)
```

I know that I cannot use comparison operators with more then one value but I cannot figure out the solution.

Comment: what is the column in paychecks to identify employees (i.e. employeeid)

Comment: Yes. The employee ID = employid

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please provide sample data and sample expected results.  "Pull out all the paychecks" can mean a lot of things.  Please clarify your question.  In addition, while you're clarifying the question, please indicate what RDBMS is involved (MYSQL, MSSQL, ...).  Don't just tag SQL without also tagging the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (use your connecting column instead of employeeid):

```
select p.* from db2.paychecks p inner join db1.employees e on p.employeeid=e.employeeid
where e.hiredate>='2020-01-01'
```

Comment: "Where" not "and"?

Comment: Thank you so much.